# Installing MYSQL - use specific PPA version/build of software

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, server, apt

For example
If I want to install mysql using PPA I can use:

```
add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/mysql-5.6
apt-get update
apt-get install mysql-server
```

But this will install 5.6.28

Is there a way to install a specific version of mysql and a specific build for example mysql 5.6.20 from:

```
https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/mysql-5.6/+build/6238786
```